# Slowed execution on second and subsequent runs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, kinect

I've been working on an intermediate-sized project in Visual Studio 2013 in C#/WPF. It relies on the Kinect SDK, and there are a good number of objects implemented in the code. When I run the debug cycle the first time (using the release configuration), execution is pretty speedy. On subsequent runs, the execution (especially of the code to connect to the... erm... Kinect) slows down significantly. I was wondering what could cause this, and what I could do to diagnose it. Are there any benchmarks in Visual Studio or things I could do to make the slowdown go away?

Comment: Not to say you won't get helpful advice on this here -- it's relevant -- but, [superuser](http://superuser.com/) might also have some good ideas about this.

Comment: @NicholasV. thank you, I'll post it over there as well.